# The difference between `_.forEach` and `$.each`

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, foreach, underscore.js

These two functions,  `_.forEach` and `$.each`, taken respectively from `underscore` and `jQuery` seems to make the same thing.

What are the possible reasons to prefer one implementation to the other?

Comment: i would not make my decision which framework to take dependent on a single method...

Comment: Underscore isn't a framework

Comment: Use the underscore version. It follows the standard.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`_.forEach` and `$.each` differs for the arguments passed to the callback.

If you use `_.forEach`, the first argument passed to the callback is the value, not the key.
So if you don't bother at all about the key you should use `_.forEach`.

Other differences:

1. `_.forEach` it will be a bit faster as it uses the native `Arrray.prototype.forEach` in modern browsers.
2. the this value is also different. jQuery's behavior doesn't follow the standard, underscore's does.

Comment: Jquery doesn't use the native foreach if available? Thx, I didn't knew that

Comment: The `this` value is also different. jQuery's behavior doesn't follow the standard, underscore's does. And underscore lets you set the `this` value with a third argument.

Answer (score 6):

Both of them mainly provide a replacement for the [forEach](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/docs/underscore.html#section-12) function that isn't available in IE8.

They don't add much if you're iterating over arrays.

The main difference, apart the order of the callback arguments, is that in jQuery the value is also available as context of the callback's call (this is why the value, less important, is only the second argument provided). This isn't really a major reason to prefer it unless you really like to avoid passing an argument to the function :

```
var product = 1;
$.each([1, 2, 3], function(){ product *= this });
```

Most often, you don't use both libraries, so you simply use the iterating function provided by the library you have.

If you happen to import both libraries, I would suggest to use the underscore function as

- it's the most similar to the standard ECMAScript function on arrays so you'll more easily migrate the day IE8 will be dead
- it's more efficient as it uses the native function when it's available :

[See source](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/docs/underscore.html#section-12) :

```
...
if (nativeForEach && obj.forEach === nativeForEach) {
     obj.forEach(iterator, context);
...
```

Comment: underscore also accepts a plain object instead of an Array. http://jsfiddle.net/zdF6D/ jQuery's feature set is *less* complete, because it doesn't let you set the `this` value of the callback via a 3rd argument.

Comment: @IHateLazy You're right. I had read the source too fast...

Comment: I really wish jQuery had its parameters switched around. I can live without being able to set the `this` value of the callback, but the flipped params drives me a little crazy.

Comment: This is, in fact, confusing. I agree to that. And the fact that you can't always use this because it may be boxed forbids you to simply always use this.

Answer (score 6):

**jQuery** looks like:

```
something.each( function(index, Element) )
```

**Underscore** looks like:

```
_.each(list, function(Element, index, list), [context])
// or
_(list).each(function(Element, index, list), [context])
```

**Native array.forEach** looks like:

```
array.forEach(function(Element, index, list), [context])
```

So:

- Underscore keeps the same argument order as native `forEach`
- There are two differences between JQuery's and Underscore's implementation:

  - JQuery sets `this` to `Element`, native and Underscore allow you to provide your own context
  - Native and underscore also provide the list itself as third argument to the callback.

---

Edit: Why is it useful to be able to set the context?

Consider that you have some kind of object:

```
var worker = new FooWorker();
worker.process(something);
worker.process(somethingElse);
```

Say you want to call that method on every value from an array.
Using the context parameter, you can simply say:

```
myArray.forEach(worker.process, worker);
```

while without it you'd need to be more verbose (and do one more function call per element):

```
// native
myArray.forEach( function(i, e) {worker.process(e);} );
// jquery
$(myArray).each( function() {worker.process(this); } );
```

This is one situation where JQuery's foreaching convention makes things less convenient.